What causes the 0x610000d4 error code on HP PageWide printers?
I'm trying to fix a HP PageWide 477dw, which initially returned the 0x610000d3 error code. I could successfully fix this error.
Now the printer goes one step further and returns error 0x610000d4.
Right before this error, the printer asks to add blank A4 paper in "Tray 2" which is the standard tray, despite there are around 30 sheets in it.
I assume the 0x610000d4 error is caused by the paper being not detected for some reason.
I am not sure which mechanical or optical component detects the presence of paper. Right behind the roll in the paper bay is kind of a leg, that seems moving freely, but it seems unlikely that this part it the one that would detect a few sheets of paper.
By also testing the printer with the paper tray from another printer of the same model, I can confirm that in my case the error does not come from the tray itself.

Edit 1
Error 0x610000d4 might be caused by the large part that can slide to the right as a black plastic roof inside the paper bay.
In my working printers, this part is pushed to the left, and its two large plastic hooks clip a horizontal metal bar. This is possible only if the lift containing the cartridges is up, which is the case.
If the cartriges lift is down, it seems impossible to have the horizontal part on the left, as it conflicts with the lift.
In the defective printer, I noticed that if the plastic part was on the right and could slide, letting the cartridge lift move in the vertical direction, the error code was 0x610000d4.
If observed that after powering the printer on and awaiting the cartridge lift to be up to slide the large part to the left (i.e. like in the working printers) and clipsing it to the hozizontal metal bar, I got again error 0x610000d3.
So both parts are conflicting in some way and error 0x610000d3 is triggered when the cartrige lift is prevented to move vertically for some reason.
As will need to watch on my working printers if the large part is moving horizontally and freeing the cartrige lift at some time.

The error 0x61000d4 may concern several printers with PageWide technology, and possibly also some models of OfficeJet product line. On HP community forums, I could not find any better answer than "Contact HP support".

What I learned by fixing error 0x610000d3 is that:

The printer successively checks its components (scanner, ink cartridges, a.s.o.) and outputs an error code as soon as a component is not answering as expected.
Just before the error code, a warning is often displayed on the printer's display, that let you know which component was being tested when the error occured. The warning in itself is often irrelevant, but however can help you to locate which component is defective. (For instance, the warning before error 0x610000d3 is about ink cartridges, and the error 0x610000d3 does not come from the cartridges themselves , but from their lifting system and its mechanism at the rear of the machine.) So, the warning has to be considered as a clue.
An error code tells you which "component group" is not answering like expected, but you will have to inspect your printer to understand what exactly triggers the error. In other words, there may be several possible causes for the same error code. For instance, this video was a huge help for me to understand that the 0x610000d3 error code was coming from the ink cartriges lifting mechanism. However, in my case, the cause was not caused by the pinion at timing 1'09'' of the video, but by the plastic encoder wheel located at its left, which had gone out of its black plastic reading canyon.

